# Issue with fetching value from registry

Tags: c#, .net

Hi i am displaying version value from registry .For fetching value from registry i did the following code.

```
     // Where WrmSpoAgentRoot= @"Software\syscon\Point Monitor\";
     string keySpoPath = SpoRegistry.WrmSpoAgentRoot; 
     RegistryKey regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keySpoPath);
```

But i want to assign this value in to a property..So i created a property "Wrmversion".But when  i am assigning this value ,,'regkey' variable is not assigning in to 
the property means intellisense is not producing 'regkey' variable(The name 'regkey' does not exist in the current context)

```
public string Wrmversion
{
    get { return m_wrmversion; }
    set { m_wrmversion = value; }
}

private string m_wrmversion = string)regkey.GetValue(
                           SpoRegistry.regValue_CurrentVersion);
```

Is there any way to assign value in to property like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this assignment inside a constructor.

Let's suppose this class is named FooBar. You should write:

```
class FooBar
{

    //other code goes here

    public FooBar()
    {
        m_wrmversion = (string)regkey.GetValue(SpoRegistry.regValue_CurrentVersion);
    }
}
```

Comment: so i did this way,is there any logical problem,,
   public class WindowsAgent
   {
       public string Wrmversion
       {
           get { return m_wrmversion; }
           set { m_wrmversion = value; }
       }
       private string m_wrmversion = null;
   }

       public WindowsAgent()
      {

         string keySpoPath = SpoRegistry.WrmSpoAgentRoot;
         RegistryKey regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keySpoPath);
         m_wrmversion = (string)regkey.GetValue(SpoRegistry.regValue_CurrentVersion);
      } // WindowsRes